# Infinite energy, helicopters and world-wide attention

Tags: internal-consistency, technological-development, energy, military, alternate-reality

Story is set in our days, modern Earth with all it's current problems and conflicts. Let's say someone had secretly found a way to produce almost infinite (reasonably infinite, of course) amount of energy in form of electricity, it's easily scale-able in power, it takes size just about standard suitcase and weight is small enough to be carried by just one man. For a "field experiment" it's used as a power source for an actual battlefield helicopter, similar to something like  MH-53 in characteristics (in terms of size, weight and capability to use on a difficult terrains to land and take off).

It's usage pretty crucial for story, as this helicopter is used as a transport for hundreds and thousands of kilometres, with range restriction only in matters of pilot endurance.

My question: is there any way to transform electric current into rotation of blades, and other outputs, needed to operate a helicopter properly? I mean, there are a lot of electric engines with enough horsepower to lift a helicopter, but they weight and are measured about as big as a helicopter itself.

Re-clarification of question: currently available electric engines, if replacing original engines ot that helicopter, will be size of a helicopter itself and weight >6 more times than original one. Do I just don't know about more reasonable e-engine solution, or there is just no any?

Sorry for any errors or misspells, English is not my native language.

Comment: Traditionally questions only containing one question are less likely to be closed and more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Removing not so crucial subquestion here: if information about such an extravagant device will slip to some powerful enough country, will it provoke worldwide hunt for that helicopter? With use of autopilot he can virtually be 100% airborne. But can it possibly gain so much interest in some military-scientific circles like DARPA, so they decide to use military power (with worldwide attention) to bring it down and experiment on it by themselves, and it will be ok, or it will be counted so aggressive, so all the other countries will be really, really angry?

Comment: This was a TV show in the 80s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airwolf

Comment: You can not just power a helicopter with it, you can mount a railgun on your helicopter.

Comment: Little comment: "Countable infinity" energy does not make sense, since energy is (at least in classical physics) is a continous quantity

Comment: @b.Lorenz I mean it's not quintillion terawatts, and it will provide electricity for countable time, so it's not really breaking any basic laws of physics like perpetual motion. I don't know proper term, and "impressively large" just doesn't sound right.

Comment: The phrase "[countably infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)" has a well-defined meaning. That meaning is incompatible with the usage of the phrase in the question. And your impressions about electric motors are simply wrong.

Comment: You make the usual confusions between *energy* and *power*.  Power is the rate at which energy is produced or used.  Energy is therefore the total power used or generated in a given period.  A Watt is a unit of power.  A watt-hour is a unit of energy.

Comment: @AlexP sorry, I'm really not good with english terminology, so I took what seemed appropriate for me. You right, it's not really correct word for what I mean, something like "realistically limited" would be better. Could you please provide some more info about what's wrong with my impressions about e-engines? To lift helicopter and engine itself it should provide enough RPM and torque for blades, and I checked some engines, which provide reasonable amount of horsepowers and PRM. They are really, really huge, and weight tons.

Comment: For example, a [Bell 206](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_206) helicopter uses one [Allison 250-C30P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allison_Model_250) engine providing about 310 kW (420 HP). An old-style Tesla Model S electric motor [weighs about 35 kg](https://chargedevs.com/newswire/elon-musk-cooling-not-power-to-weight-ratio-is-the-challenge-with-ac-induction-motors/) and produces 270 kW (362 HP); an all-wheel-drive Tesla Model S has two of them, 70 kg, 540 kW (724 HP). I don't know from where you got the idea that electric motors must be huge beasts, but it's definitely incorrect.

Comment: @AlexP I'm sorry, but Bell 206 is a **1-1.5 ton** helicopter with a single **310 kWt** engine. It can provide room for only **4 passengers**. And MH-53 is a **14.5 ton** helicopter with **2 engines 3200 kWt each**, with capacity of **37 or 55 passengers**, onboard guns and rapels. Even more - it's length is more than two times bigger. For example - that's a picture of a somewhat around [4000 horsepower 3000 kW](https://www.dangelointernational.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/EM078_07.jpg) electric engine rotor, just googled up. And direct replacing will need for two of them.

Comment: You should also try to find a [picture of the 3200 kW engines](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:T-64_turbo_shaft_of_a_MH-53E_%27Sea_Dragon%27_helicopter.jpg) of the MH-53... They are not small.

Comment: @AlexP So, it looks that I was mistaken! Do such engines really meet all requrements of military helicopter, like torque/horsepower, throttle range and durability? If so and if you can provide some reading about that - I'll be really happy!)

Comment: No, they don't. Nobody has seriously made electric motors for aviation. There will absolutely be a period of five or ten years until engineers understand what is needed and how to approach the required reliability etc. High-power high-reliability electric motors are currently used either in industry or on submarines; in both applications volume and weight are non-issues. Scaling up modern motors such as those used by electric automobiles won't happen overnight. We may even see innovative approaches, such as using multiple small motors to provide graceful degradation...

Comment: @AlexP strangely enough, there was a second link to electric engine with enough kW parameters. My comment is about second link. About link with engines of MH-53 - yes, they are something about 2 meters long and 1 meter in diameter, and it's not so big as rotor on my photo.
So, there is no actual current solution to problem from a question. It's really just "add more boosters", sadly enough( I'll just use "cutting edge super-efficient electric rotor" and hope for the best. Anyway, thanks for help! If you still interested and if you'll find something reliable - please, use answers for wotes!)

Comment: @Lemis , simply delete the mention of "countably .." - your usage is utterly incorrect mathematically and physically  :)   It's a fun question, just delete that bit.

Comment: this is a great question, *"currently available electric engines, if replacing original engines of a MH-53, will be .. what size and weight?"*  Nobody has answered the question yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you have a small, man-portable device capable of providing electrical power in any quantity desired.  Daniel Thomas Shipstone would be proud!

Brushless electrical motors are commonly used to provide lift and momentum in airborne drones which operate very similarly to helicopters.  The great challenge in creating a load-bearing drone is not the weight of the engines, but instead the weight of the batteries needed to power the engines for long-distance flight.  If you ignore the weight of their fuel/power sources, electrical engines have demonstrated higher [power to weight ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-to-weight_ratio) than conventional fuel engines.
Since you invention effectively solves the power-source weight problem, there are no obvious technical reasons that you can't create a war-worthy electric helicopter.

Comment: Last time I've checked, helicopters like this used **two** combustion engines 4k-4.5k horsepowers each, and just **one** electric engine with that much power was half size of a helicopter itself. If someone want to fit two of those engines in helicopter - he will need a slightly bigger helicopter :)

Comment: I just found a similar question on [an associated forum](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26910/could-an-electric-engine-provide-the-same-performance-as-jet-engines-on-current).  A lot of the answers support your assertion that size and weight are still the issue.  Seems that the advantage in power-to-weight that electric holds over combustion in the small scale, inverts at height power levels.  Thanks for helping me learn something new.

Comment: you right, all of the answers on this question is about "yes, just use e-engine", even if I stated in the question itself, that problem isn't about "should I use electric engines?", but about "they are too big to use, what is the way to avoid using USS Enterprise with rotor blades on top of it?" :) From your link I can see that e-engines provide about 1 kW/kg, so just to replace 1 ton and 6 MW of original engines of MH-53 I need six tons of electric engines (and it's without any mechanics around involved)...

Comment: Thumbs up for the Shipstone reference.

Comment: Modern electric motors such as those used for electric automobiles provide better than 10 kW/kg, so using your crude calculation those 6 MW would need about 600 kg of engine.

Answer (score 3):

You have functionally unlimited amounts of electricity? **Just use electric-powered jet engines.** Jet engines have four stages, only one of which, the combustion chamber, is chemically-powered, and the burning jet fuel is primarily used simply to increase the temperature of the air in the combustion chamber. With unlimited electricity, you can simply use something like a tesla coil to generate high-temperature plasma in what was the combustion chamber to do the job of heating the air instead of fuel.

Comment: Pretty neat solution, but doesn't jet engines used for planes and overall plane-like motion? Helicopters don't need a runway to land, they can hover and can be used for troop landing, and planes are not. Of course, if it's not something like [convertiplane from Terminator](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/terminator/images/0/08/HK_Aerial_2029.jpg).

Comment: A lot of helicopters use jet engines, too; they're called turboshaft engines. They just use them to spin the helicopter rotors rather than providing thrust directly or spinning turbofans like most big passenger planes do.

Comment: With unlimited power why spin rotors? Build an electric Harrier Jumpjet.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 the most efficient internal combustion engine converts just 44% of the  potential fuel energy entering the engine into rotation. Air cooled electric motors using compressed air bearings can produce 95% efficiency with only 5% lost as waste heat, (that's not quite a true comparison as you get some loses to wiring resistance etc... *before* that energy gets to the engine) you might need a bigger helicopter but with infinite energy to pump into a 95% efficient engine system you should get it off the ground at some point where the economy of scale favours you.

Comment: Well, if I need a bigger helicopter to fit those engines - it will incrementally add to weight, so I will need an even more powerful engines (to lift a bigger helicopter and themselves). Even if it will not lead to [N1-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N1_(rocket)) project, it will make using it on battlefield remarkably harder, as size will increase and speed will decline. KSP-like "just add more boosters" is logical, but in the same time is somewhat wrong.

Comment: @Lemis Like I said there will be somewhere along the line that the economy of scale works, probably.

Comment: for now I'm just using words like "super-efficient rotor", allowing to not draw much attention of anyone in novel world (but really large, silent not-fueling helicopter will draw it), but it looks too StarTrek-ish. I might just toss there "extraconductive zero-spinary unequal tetrastable torsionic engine" and it wouldn't look less realistic. Helicopter is large part of the story, so I can't just let it be, because 99% of other stuff is much more real-looking, power source is really only one not really beliavable stuff. And without proper explanation I can as well say "it's just magic"(